# MongoDB average aggregation using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Good afternoon everyone.

I have an Array inside a MongoDB Document. I wan't to find a `Volume` inside it and make an average for whole collection on `Volume` parameter.

**Document inside a MongoDB:**

[image: MongoDB screen]

As you can see I have array inside array. I will have a lot of the same type documents and I need to make an average calculation between every document on `Volume`parameter.

**Problematic area of code(This is not working just showcasing my try.**

```
function simplePipeline(db, callback) {
    const collection = db.collection('ADABTC');
    collection.aggregate(
        [
            { '$group': { 'Volume': { '$avg': 'Array.Volume' } } }
        ],
        function(err, cursor) {
            assert.equal(err, null);

            cursor.toArray(function(err, documents) {
                console.log(documents)
                callback(documents);
            });
        }
    );
}
```

Just in case I can connect to DB `username:password` just for example.

How I should specify it NodeJS?

**NodeJS Full Code**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://username:password@ip.adress.port/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'Crypto';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function(err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    const db = client.db(dbName);

    simplePipeline(db, function() {
        client.close();
    });
});

function simplePipeline(db, callback) {
    const collection = db.collection('ADABTC');
    collection.aggregate(
        [
            { '$group': { 'Volume': { '$avg': 'Array.Volume' } } }
        ],
        function(err, cursor) {
            assert.equal(err, null);

            cursor.toArray(function(err, documents) {
                console.log(documents)
                callback(documents);
            });
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) syntax is just wrong:

> Groups input documents by the specified _id expression and for each distinct grouping, outputs a documen

A `$group` stage must have a `_id` field specified. to group the entire collection just put any constant there.

```
{
    '$group': {
        _id: null,
        'Volume': {
            '$avg': '$Array.Volume'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Tom, thanks for your answer! When I'm doing your way I receive - [ { _id: null, Volume: null } ] in console log.

Comment: add `$` to your variable call - i edited the answer.